# Boost program options: positional and multitoken options

Tags: c++, boost-program-options

How does `boost::program_options` parse or manage an input when both multitoken and positional options are allowed?

For example:

```
./app.sample pos1 --multitokenoption a b c d pos2
```

How does boost know when a `multitokenoption` finishes and a positional option begins?

Obviously, the most logical allowed behaviour would be that a multitoken option must be present as last parameter, just as happens with default arguments in function parameters, but the documentation says nothing about it.

Comment: Why do you think the `multitokenoption` will finish? It will eat all the remaining tokens. If 'pos2' is required, then it will be an exception thrown.

Answer (score 6):

There are three way to mark the end of values for a multitoken option:

1. Another option:

   ```
       ./app.sample pos1 --multitokenoption a b c d --regularoption v pos2
   ```
2. Option name for the positional option (almost the #1):

   ```
       ./app.sample pos1 --multitokenoption a b c d --pos2 pos2
   ```
3. Double-dash:

   ```
       ./app.sample pos1 --multitokenoption a b c d -- pos2
   ```

Otherwise the multi-token option won't know where to stop - nothing magical.

Comment: But boost::program_option has no native support for such double dash, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: It works for me. Boost = 1.55.0, Compiler = GCC 4.8.1, OS = Xubuntu 3.11.10.3